# GET request on Express.js is returning all values from database

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

i'm trying to return one specific user's data from using GET method on Express.js by using **Form**. But when using form, it's returning all the values.

this is the index.html code :

```
<form action="http://localhost:1234/users" method="get">
   id <input type="number" name="id" placeholder="enter id" /><br/>
</form>
```

and the app.js code :

```
    app.get('/users/:id', (request, response) => {
    const id = request.params.id;

    pool.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ${id}`, id, (error, result) => {
        if (error) throw error;

        response.send(result);
    });
});
```

basically when i'm sending request through the url **`http://localhost:1234/users/1`** then, only the specified user's data is shown. But when I'm using **form** to send the data, what I saw the main problem was the url, now the url becomes like that **`http://localhost:1234/users?id=1`**  . For this reason, it's returning all the values from database. How can I solve this? I know maybe, it's a easy one, but as new to node.js and express, I've tried several methods but on form it's not working.

Comment: As you noted, when you submit the form the URI changes, try to make an ajax call (maybe with jQuery or other library) directly to the route you defined

Comment: @JuanDM can't it be done without jQuery on Express ? as when, I send get method without using express just normal http server, it worked fine then

Comment: While I would do this using Ajax as @JuanDM mentioned, I drafted an Express-only answer if it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to compromise your database.

Comment: There seems to be a glitch - Why is the route `users?id=1` is getting matched with `users/:id`? They shouldn't match, so I'm wondering, is there any more to the code that @InsaneDA might have not pasted here.

Comment: @HS no, they are not matching. that's the problem here. This's why it's sending all rows from the database instead only the required one

Comment: Wait that's true, id is a mandatory parameter in that route. There is another route in OP's code handling /users that simply returns all the users all the time.

Comment: @InsaneDA - the callback that you have shown in the above route will not be called if the matching is failed. So, it should be some other callback/route-handler that is being activated something like - "app.get('users'..."

Comment: @MadWard sorry, i just checked that there is another route, this is why it's sending all the rows

Comment: yah i figured that out @HS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most natural solution would be to use Ajax to send a query on form submit, and to disable default behaviour of the form (`<event>.preventDefault()`).

I will tackle a more hacky way that doesn't involve modifying the client, but only the server:

1. Make :id an optional parameter by adding a question mark
2. Handling both cases: if `req.params.id` is defined but `req.query.id` isn't, or if `req.query.id` is defined but `req.params.id` isn't.

---

```
app.get('/users/:id?', (request, response) => {
    const paramId = request.params.id;
    const queryId = request.query.id;
    var id;

    if(paramId && !queryId)
        id = paramId;
    else if(queryId && !paramId)
        id = queryId;

    if(!id)
        return response.send('Please specify an id');

    pool.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ${id}`, id, (error, result) => {
        if (error) throw error;

        response.send(result);
    });
});
```

With this, the following URLS are fine:

- `http://localhost:1234/users/1`
- `http://localhost:1234/users?id=1`

Those aren't:

- `http://localhost:1234/users/`
- `http://localhost:1234/users/1?id=1`

Comment: but it's still returning all the columns. Do i have to change anything on the Form?

Comment: I don't see any reason for it to return all columns since id has to be defined, did you copy the snippet verbatim?

Comment: yes, i did. but still it's working for only `http://localhost:1234/users/1` . not for this one which i send request from the html form `http://localhost:1234/users?id=1`